# Not seeing my results in a MessageDialog

Tags: java

I am trying to create a wizard to convert units of length.  I am able to create an `OptionDialog` and have the user select what type of conversion to do; however, I am unable to display my results in a `MessageDialog` at the end.  Here is the code I am using:

```java
import java.util.Scanner; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class LengthConversion { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double cmValue, inchValue;
        int choice;

        //Create Scanner object
        Scanner fromKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

       //Customise Object text
       Object[] options = {"cm-to-inch", "inch-to-cm", "Cancel"};

       //Option Dialog box
       choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choice an option", "Length Conversion", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[2]);

      //Begin 'if' Statement
      if (choice == 0) {
          //Show Input Dialog Box
          String inputType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the cm to convert:");
         //Read value that user type
         cmValue = fromKeyboard.nextDouble();
         //Compute cm to inch
         inchValue = cmValue/2.54;
         //Preview result
         String outputType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, +inchValue+" inches");
     } else {
         //Ask user to enter value
         String inputType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the inch to convert:");
         //Read value that user type
         inchValue = fromKeyboard.nextDouble();
         //compute inch to cm
         cmValue = inchValue * 2.54;
         //Display result
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, +cmValue+" cm");
     } //end of 'else' Statement
 } //end main
} //end class Length Conversion
```

What do I need to do differently to get the results to be displayed at the end?

Comment: Remove the first + here: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, +cmValue+" cm");` so that it's: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cmValue+" cm");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the choice = 0 (with choice = 1, solution is similar), This code has the following line:

```
cmValue = fromKeyboard.nextDouble();
```

which is basically waiting for you to enter a number from the keyboard. The program is hanging there waiting for you to enter a number.

For the solution, please comment it out and add:

```
//          cmValue = fromKeyboard.nextDouble();
            cmValue = Integer.parseInt(inputType);
```

Answer (score 0):

The app work, but is with very bad design.

This is much better example

```
public class LengthConversion {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double cmValue, inchValue;
        int choice;

        //Customise Object text
        Object[] options = {"cm-to-inch", "inch-to-cm", "Cancel"};

        //Option Dialog box
        choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choice an option", "Length Conversion", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[2]);

        String inputType;
        switch(choice) {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                try {
                    //Show Input Dialog Box
                    inputType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the cm to convert:");
                    cmValue = Double.parseDouble(inputType);
                    //Compute cm to inch
                    inchValue = cmValue / 2.54;
                    //Preview result
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, + inchValue + " inches");
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                break;

            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                try {
                    //Ask user to enter value
                    inputType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the inch to convert:");
                    //Read value that user type
                    inchValue = Double.parseDouble(inputType);
                    //compute inch to cm
                    cmValue = inchValue * 2.54;
                    //Display result
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, + cmValue + " cm");
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a rough skeleton. To become a really good generic nature of operations must be exported in a separate function.